# geom_arc_bar fill does not apply correctly to the right segment

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

```
library(ggforce)

data <- structure(list(startSegment = c(0, 1.570796327, 3.141592654, 4.71238898), endSegment = c(1.570796327, 3.141592654, 4.71238898,  6.283185307), startRadius = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), endRadius = c(119.8964009, 119.8964009, 119.8964009, 119.8964009), CountOccurence = c(10L, 100L, 200L, 300L), midSegment = c(0.785398163, 2.35619449, 3.926990817, 5.497787144), midRadius = c(71.93784053, 71.93784053, 71.93784053, 71.93784053), text_x = c(50.86773486, -50.86773486, -50.86773486, 50.86773486), text_y = c(50.86773486, 50.86773486, -50.86773486, -50.86773486), midSegmentDegrees = c(45L, 135L, 225L, 315L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          -4L))

ggplot(data) +
  geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = startRadius, r = endRadius, start = startSegment, end = endSegment, fill = CountOccurence)) +
geom_text(aes(
    x = text_x,
    y = text_y,
    angle = midSegmentDegrees,
    label = CountOccurence
  ),
  size = 10/.pt,
  color = "white"
  ) +
coord_fixed()
```

[image: Wrong fill color]

As it can be seen in the screenshot, the brightest blue is in the segment with 100 counts, but should be in the segment with 300.

Am I doing sth. wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You misspecified the coordinates for your labels. The "100" should be in the bottom right wide, the "300" in the top left. Of course could you also switch the start and end points for the segments if you want the "100" in the top left and the 300 in the bottom right.

```r
library(ggforce)

data[2, c("text_x", "text_y")] <- -data[2, c("text_x", "text_y")]
data[4, c("text_x", "text_y")] <- -data[4, c("text_x", "text_y")]

ggplot(data) +
  geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = startRadius, r = endRadius, start = startSegment, end = endSegment, fill = CountOccurence)) +
  geom_text(aes(
    x = text_x,
    y = text_y,
    angle = midSegmentDegrees,
    label = CountOccurence
  ),
  size = 10 / .pt,
  color = "white"
  ) +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]